# FutureBuilder get data only one time

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-futurebuilder

I have to get a List from Realtime Database (Firebase). I have no problem to get first time my list but if I go back and return on the future builder activity I get no data.
This is my code:

```
import 'package:cleverpot/Utily/Constants.dart';
import 'package:cleverpot/Utily/Function.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class AxisChart extends StatelessWidget {
  AxisChart(this.title);

  final String title;
  final FirebaseDatabase db =
      FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL: Constans.url_database);
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  List records = [];

  Future getData() async {
    Map data = {};
    db
        .reference()
        .child(_auth.currentUser.uid)
        .child("records")
        .once()
        .then((value) {
      data = Map.of(value.value);

      records = data[FunctionHelper.selectFolder(title)];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: getData(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Center(
            child: SfCartesianChart(
              title: ChartTitle(text: "Ultima settimana"),
              primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(),
              series: <LineSeries<Records, int>>[
                LineSeries(
                    dataSource: <Records>[
                      Records(1, records[0]),
                      Records(2, records[1]),
                      Records(3, records[2]),
                      Records(4, records[3]),
                      Records(5, records[4]),
                      Records(6, records[5]),
                      Records(7, records[6]),
                    ],
                    xValueMapper: (Records records, _) => records.day,
                    yValueMapper: (Records records, _) => records.records)
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}

class Records {
  Records(this.day, this.records);
  final int day;
  final int records;
}
```

If I use listen method in getData() function instead of once I resolve the problem but i don't want to stay on listen for the data. Anyone can help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: you can  use StreamBuilder for that

Comment: what is the difference ?

Comment: By listening to a Stream you'll get each new value when database updated.

Comment: ok thank you, i will try

Comment: why you didn't make the `db.reference().child(_auth.currentUser.uid).child("records").once().then((value) { data= Map.of(value.value);records = data[FunctionHelper.selectFolder(title)];});` make await ?

Comment: yeah, i solve with this. Now the problem is that the ConnectionState is ever on Active and never Done

Comment: I solved, thank you

Answer (score 0):

For this example, I will use firebase firestore but I think the procedure is similar

**1. Creating a stream**

```
stream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
```

**2. Real-time read using StreamBuilder**

```
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: stream,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading"); // this will prevent from null error
        }
        //when succeedeed to get data, you can make some list to show them
        //
        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
          Map<String, dynamic> data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(data['full_name']),
              subtitle: Text(data['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
```

source code from [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/)

Comment: I try a similar code like yours, but ConnectionState is even on active Value and never done. But i have all data what I need.

Comment: so I solved, thank you !